# MediaCodec from another app causing issues

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

I'm aware that I can check the max supported instances of `MediaCodec` using [getMaxSupportedInstances](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#getMaxSupportedInstances())

The problem I have is - If another application is using `MediaCodec`, and I open my application then my application fails. In other words, if another developer is not handling the release of `MediaCodec` correctly then my application will "suffer" from this.

I doubt that there is a way to release current instances of `MediaCodec` which my application did not create?

What I currently do is, I use a `try/catch` block to check if there was an error initializing/creating an instance of `MediaCodec`, as shown below:

```
try {
    //Prepare MediaCodec
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    Log.e("Log", "Thread was interrupted");
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Show alert dialog
}
```

In the alert dialog, I let the user know that he/she should make sure that there isn't any other video/camera applications open in the background.

This is not ideal, but I couldn't find any other solution.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**Edit**

Just to add, the exception I get is `Error 0xffffec77`